# psycopg2/psql unable to connect to the postgres db

Tags: django, postgresql, azure

I have two VPSes:

- webserver 10.0.0.5
- dbserver 10.0.0.6

I've set a few firewall rules on them:

```
#webserver to allow for the 10.0.0.6 dbserver
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.6 --dport 5432 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.0.0.6 --sport 5432 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
#dbserver to allow for the 10.0.0.5 webserver
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.5 --dport 5432 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.0.0.5 --sport 5432 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I'm using Azure VMs with static IPs. I don't believe I need to define any security rules on their firewall, because the traffic is internal to the hypervisor group (I can ssh from one VM to another fine).

I can't `./manage.py migrate` my django app because psycopg2 can't connect to the database server. (I believe my `settings.py` is correct.)

The relevant entry in pg_hba.conf:

```
#accept connections from the 10.0.0.0 subnet
local   all  10.0.0.0/24    trust
```

The relevant entry in postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost, 10.0.0.5'
```

I can connect with `psql` on the dbserver locally. I am unable to connect with `psql -h 10.0.0.6 -U postgres -W`  over the network from the webserver. Just to make sure it isn't the firewall rules, when I flush all rules from the db server and try to connect from the webserver, it tells me:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "10.0.0.6" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

`nmap 10.0.0.6 -p5432` says that:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-11 05:42 UTC
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.6
Host is up (0.0026s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql
```

So clearly postgres is not listening on 5432 like it's supposed to be. I guess I have something wrong with pg_hba.conf or postgresql.conf, but I can't see what.

Edit: I opened up port 5432 to the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet in the hypervisor firewall just in case. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you enabled postgres itself to allow remote connections?  Check your `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: I've updated with the config info. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing postgresql.conf and it seems that listen_addresses is the list of destination addresses, not source addresses. Changing this entry to `10.0.0.6` fixed the problem.